# c# Datagridview column width - Index was out of range. error

Tags: c#, datagridview, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to change the column width of my second column in datagridview. 
I keep on getting - Index out of range error.
If I click on datagridview, it shows that it has binded with my datatable and all the columns and data are showing.
Tried everything and are stuck, please help

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dt.Columns["ID"].SetOrdinal(0);
        dt.Columns["Name"].SetOrdinal(1);
        dt.Columns["SKU"].SetOrdinal(2);
        dt.Columns["Price"].SetOrdinal(3);
        dt.Columns["QTY"].SetOrdinal(4);
        dt.Columns["Status"].SetOrdinal(5);

        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        bindingSource1.DataSource = dt;

        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;

        dataGridView2.Location = new Point(0, 0);

        dataGridView2.ClientSize = new Size(850, 500);
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView2); // Display table


        dataGridView2.Columns[1].Width = 300;    // ERROR here
```

I have also tried

```
DataGridViewColumn firstcolumn = dataGridView2.Columns[1];
        firstcolumn.Width = 300;
```

Comment: Do you have AutoGenerateColumns on? Adding columns to the datasource is not equivalent to adding them to a gridview.

Comment: I have tried with AutoGenerateColumns set as True and False, same error.